# Login user in whole laravel system - web and api

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, laravel-passport

I have a big problem (for my self)

we have a laravel project that some pages with livewire and laravel blade (auth with session) and some other with react and API (passport bearers token)

user login with API in react page and logged in panel
but I have problem to login user in laravel web guard

I make a middleware

```
 $apiKey = $request->bearerToken();
        if(!empty($apiKey)){
            $user = request()->user();
            if(!empty($user) && !auth()->guard('web')->check()) {
                Auth::guard('web')->login($user, true);
            }
        }
```

but I think this is bad practice

what can i do?

site structure is like this:

--login page with react and API

---- user dashboard with react and API

---- user ticket system with livewire and laravel blade file (session)

---- user QA system with livewire and laravel blade file (session)